# Currency pipe not working when using a variable from a subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

My currency pipe is not working when using a variable from a Subscription in `ngOnInit`. The pipe however works when I assign it hardcoded in `ngOnInit`.

```
<span>{{ expense.amount | currency:currency }}</span>
```

```js
currency!: string;    

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.currency = 'EUR'; // component shows correct currency
  this.currencySubscription = this.authService.getUserSubject().subscribe(response => {
      this.currency = response.currency; // correct currency, but not updated in component
    });
}
```

Anybody who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to work in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-70633212?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: It actually sounds like the change is just not detected because `getUserSubject()` is probably asynchronous. So try triggering change detection manually.

Comment: maybe response does not have currency `console.log(response.currency)`

Comment: Two possibilities: the subscribe isn't returning a value or you have ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush set for this component. If you let us know we can offer something more specific.

Comment: When updating the currency in another component, the observable is returning the correct (new) currency, but the new currency is not updated in the view. Also I never used ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: Okay - I seem to remember that pipes only change value when you pass a new value in. What could be happening is that the expense already exists, runs through the pipe (which returns some default value), then the pipe updates, but it isn't listening for that. You could put an *ngIf="!!currency" on that span to see if it an order of operations thing.

Comment: Don't subscribe to the Observable in this manner. Create an Observable which maps the result to its currency attribute and then use the async pipe in the template to subscribe to the final Observable. Subscribing to an Observable in order to assign its emissions to a static variable is an Angular anti-pattern.